# C# - Comecar a desenvolver .Net

Tags: c#

Tendo já alguns conhecimentos em php,javascript,html, css,framework de design responsivo ,tais como, bootstrap e semantic-ui, e como o meu foco (gosto) principal é desenvolver aplicacões para a web, gostaria de saber a melhor maneira (tutoriais, concelhos, etc) para começar a desenvolver c# .net.

Comment: Antes de mais nada, seja bem vindo ao Stackoverflow em Português (ou como costumamos chamar, SOpt). Acredito que sua pergunta esteja fora do padrão do SOpt, [leia isto](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Considere também fazer um [tour](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour) muito rápido e útil para sua "estadia" em nossa comunidade.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Minha sugestão é você estudar C# e se preciso refinar o paradigma OO, aprofundar bastante sobre os conceitos por trás das aplicações WEB, como funcionam os frameworks utilizados na plataforma .NET(MVC é o principal na minha visão).

Eu aprendo entendendo bem a teoria e depois aplicando na pratica, você pode pegar o que você já fez(faria) com a stack em PHP e repetir em C#, lhe proporcionara o entendimento das diferenças das duas plataformas.